# What is "Prediction Accuracy (AUC)", and how is it the number conducted in Machine Learning?

Tags: machine-learning, prediction, accuracy

Here is the link in question: http://applymagicsauce.com/documentation.html

When the Cambridge University Psychometric Center's "Apply Magic Sauce" defines how their `Prediction Accuracy (AUC)` system works, this is what they say:

> Prediction accuracy is expressed as the correlation between the AMS prediction and the actual score. Accuracy of 1 indicates a perfect accuracy, whereas the accuracy of 0 indicates a random guess.

What is "the actual score"? In simple english, how is it calculated? I'm relatively new to these concepts, and I would just like to know how accuracy rates are calculated in machine learning.

When the documentation page states:

> The model was build (and the accuracy validated) using a sample of 98,000 people.

What exactly do they mean? How was it validated, and what is the simplest way of doing so with a text classification system?

Comment: Without reading the link, AUC typically refers to area under the ROC curve. However, that does not fit the description, since a random model has area under the ROC curve equal to 50% rather than 0. Secondly, the ambiguous use of accuracy in the quoted description is very confusing.

Comment: What is ROC? @MarcClaesen

Comment: [Receiver Operating Characteristic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic).

Comment: But it seems to be measuring the ratios of false positives to true positives- how does it really know if the algorithm has interpreted something incorrectly? Wouldn't only a human be able to determine that? I'm new to this, as you can see. @MarcClaesen

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the page linked, there are two metrics used to measure predictive accuracy of the algorithm.

1.The first is the usual Area Under the Curve (AUC) of the Receiver Operator Characteristic. As explained in the comments, AUC ranges from 0.5 to 1, with 1 being perfect classification and 0.5 being no better than luck.

[image]

Since there are only two outcomes, the algorithm can either classify positive correctly, or incorrectly.  Similar to flipping a coin, chance will predict correctly 50% of the time, giving 0.5 AUC a "worthless" accuracy.  As you increase from 0.5 to 1, your algorithm gets better and better at correctly classifying outcomes.

These algorithms are usually trained on a training set to tune parameters and tested on a test set to determine their accuracy and applicability. The AUC is found on the second table on the page.

2.The second of the metrics used is simply the correlation between the predicted outcome and the actual outcome.  This was used because the outcomes were not binary; they were linear, and thus classification was inappropriate.

This has the range 0 to 1, as there can be 0 correlation between the predicted and actual outcomes. The correlation is found on the first "linear" table on the page.

As for the second part of your question, the 98,000 person sample that they mentioned most probably had known outcomes.  For example, if your algorithm predicted a case (1), you could compare it to the actual known data to see if your algorithm predicted a true positive (TP) or a false positive (FP).  This is how they measure the accuracy.

As for the text classification system, you would need to provide more details, perhaps a separate question for that might be appropriate.

Comment: So that sample of "known outcomes" was most likely croudsourced? So it's basically a probability? Thanks again for your response.

Comment: @seanlevan Perhaps not crowdsourced, but collected in some way by the researchers. May be a survey or a questionnaire of some sort, dependant on the outcome. Those sample sizes are huge for psychometrics, so it might be an online thing.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, and the way that you simplified it to make sense. AUC ROC is basically just a plot comparison of the two variables, false positives and true positives?

Comment: @seanlevan The ROC is a graphical comparison between TP and FP, while the AUC is the area under that curve. Just wanted to make that distinction. If you're ever looking to see if one model significantly classifies the same data better than another, look into Delong's Test or bootstrapping. Just if you're ever doing it yourself. Glad to be of help.

Comment: So the image in your post is *not* AUC? What's the difference then? I don't think I absolutely understand the distinction.

Comment: What would be the use of AUC vs ROC?

Comment: On another note, I looked up Delong's Test and didn't get much accessible information on it, other than research papers. Is there any summary of what it is in a clear manner?

Comment: @seanlevan The ROC is the graph, whereas the AUC is the number that represents the total area under the curve.  So the picture above shows three ROC lines, wheras the Area under the curve (AUC) statistics of these ROCs are ~ 0.5, 0.7, and 0.9 (just by eyeballing it). The distinction is just that the ROC is the curve, wheras the AUC is the area under that curve.

Comment: The Delong's test is used to compare two different models fitting the same data (correlated ROC, doesn't mean the same thing as usual correlated). It's trying to see if there is a significant difference between the area under the curves for the two algorithms.  If there is, you can say that one algorithm predicts significantly (P < 0.05) better than another on the same data. Making your way through their [original paper](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/3203132) is probably the best, if not the most painless, way to understand. It's good to practice going back to the source for information

Comment: Don't worry about understanding everything; general concepts are all you need at this point. But saying that, I mentioned the test as more of an off-hand comment because I thought you might find it helpful eventually.  I wouldn't worry about it for now.

Comment: how is " Area under the curve" calculated? Thanks again.

Comment: It's the integral from 0 to 1 on the ROC function.  Imagine that by drawing a curve on graph paper and counting all the boxes that are under the curve.

Comment: So it's the height under the curve.

Comment: Kind of.  It's the shaded area under the curve.  [This isn't exactly what we're talking about](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/28/Riemann_integral_regular.gif), but it will help you to visualize.  I'm pretty sure you have the right idea.

Comment: How is that shaded area calculated though?

Comment: [Generally like this](http://www.mathsrevision.net/advanced-level-maths-revision/pure-maths/calculus/area-under-curve), but there are different methods used for ROC curves.  You would never have to do it manually though, any statistical package can do it for you. [ROC AUC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic#Area_under_the_curve) is calculated like this, give or take.  There are variations.

Comment: How did you "eyeball" it then?

Comment: After doing a few hundred of them, you get a feel just by looking at it :P

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22247/discussion-between-seanlevan-and-chris-c).